# kendo upload not remove row when click "Remove" button

Tags: asynchronous, upload, asyncfileupload, unlink

The upload procedure working correctly, but when I try "Remove" to any uploaded file, the file will be deleted correctly, but the row in the html page still like before the click!
How I can remove row after "Remove" button click?

this here the code:

```
<script>
  $(function() {

     $("#upload").kendoUpload({
         async: {
                    saveUrl: "modules/save.php",
                    removeUrl: "modules/remove.php",
                    autoUpload: true,
                    multiple: true
                }
            });

    });

</script>
```

and here is the remove.php:

```
    <?php
           $targetdir = "../files/";
           $targetPath = $targetdir.$_POST["fileNames"];
           unlink($targetPath);
           echo "";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this question: [KendoUI Uploader Remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052758/kendoui-uploader-remove)

For me, changing the return type did it.

From

```
public ActionResult RemoveFile(string[] fileNames)
{
    return Content("");
}
```

To

```
public ActionResult RemoveFile(string[] fileNames)
{
    return Json("");
}
```

I left my SaveFile() function with `return Content("");`

Answer (score 0):

`<?php
    $targetdir = "../files/";
    $targetPath = $targetdir.$_POST["fileNames"];
    unlink($targetPath);
    echo "{}";
?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
...
async: {
    saveUrl: "modules/save.php",
    removeUrl: "modules/remove.php",
    autoUpload: true,
    multiple: true,
    removeField: "fileNames[]"
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is a good idea to provide some explanation text as to how the code solves the issue.

Comment: You need to add "removeField" option with the name of the input.(The name of the form field submitted to the Remove URL)