# KendoUI Uploader Remove

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I've got the kendo ui uploader working no problems when uploading a file using the following js:

```
$(function () {
    //uploading
    $("#filename_trigger").kendoUpload({
        async: {
            autoUpload: true,
            saveUrl: $("#upload_url").val(),
            removeUrl: $("#delete_upload_url").val(),
            removeField: "filename",
            saveField: "filename"
        },
        select: function (e) {
            $.each(e.files, function (index, value) {
                ext = value.extension.toLowerCase();
                if (ext != '.jpg' && ext != '.png') {
                    alert('Only images are allowed!');
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        },
        success: function (e) {
            alert(e.operation);
            if (e.operation == "upload") {
                // Array with information about the uploaded files
                var files = e.files;
                $("#filename").val(e.response.filename);
                pushNotification("File uploaded");
            }

            if (e.operation == "remove") {
                pushNotification("File removed");
            }
        }});
});
```

However when it comes to removing a file, it's doesn't remove the file from the div. If I output the responseStatus using a function, it's says it's fine, and the file is actually deleted with a 200 header back from the server. Any ideas why it would be throwing an error, do I have to return back a particular string for it know that the delete was successfull?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update and use the latest internal build, it should be fixed.

I assume that the problem was due to the jQuery breaking change - the empty response is not valid JSON anymore. Or you can try to return some dummy json just to avoid that parsing problem.